# Can't print since Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, windows-10-upgrade

I've got two PCs, both of which were upgraded to Windows 10 - one from 7, one from 8.1.

Since then both have been able to print to a soft PDF printer only - neither has successfully printed on any physical printer, the queue just stalls and goes nowhere. This has been verified on multiple printers, and drivers have been uninstalled and reinstalled.

I can't see anything obvious wrong elsewhere though. Is there something else I should be checking or fixing to get them printing again?

Comment: Was the printer itself turned off and on?

Comment: Multiple printers, multiple times, drivers have been reinstalled. The problem isn't in the printer hardware, and if it's in drivers it's a surprising one.

Comment: Have you checked that the "Print Spooler" service is set to automatic?Even if it's set to automatic I would try starting/restarting it manually.(To open the service manager press the WINDOWS key on your keyboard and search for "Services".)

Comment: Do you physically connect (via USB) the printers or are they network printers? Does the OS recognise the printers as online or offline? Does the OS recognise the printers at all?